# "The game module *project name* could not be loaded" Unreal Engine 4.26

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4

My Unreal Engine 4.26 project will not open. I am on windows 10 if that helps at all. I've tried reinstalling UE4, and found nothing that worked online.

[The game module could not be loaded error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HCK2.png)

Here is the log (due to length restrictions here is a link):

[UE4 Log](https://controlc.com/6b2b24ad)

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for someone, you can also check here, there is a more generic version of this error and a detailed answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77348549/the-game-module-x-could-not-be-loaded-there-may-be-an-operating-system-error

Answer (score 1):

In the folder that holds your project, and with the project not open in the editor, delete the following folders: intermediate, saved, and binaries. Everything in those folders is temporary and will be recreated by the editor when needed. You will then need to rebuild the project in Visual Studio and after that build completes should be able to open the project in the editor.

Comment: Rebuilding the project in visual studio does not work (I'm using vs2019), most of the project files say "unloaded" and doesn't let me rebuild the project, opening the project in ue4 and having it automatically rebuild it does not work either as it crashes and the same problem happens again

[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/xovGj2D)

Answer (score 0):

Check plugins it may not be any